# How can I temporarily disable PaperTrail when reifying a version?

Tags: ruby, undo-redo, paper-trail-gem

I am using `paper_trail` for undo/redo functionality in my site and am having a problem when I call `reify.save` on a `version` in that on `save` and new `PaperTrail::Version` gets created.

Is there a way to turn off PaperTrail during the saving of a reified object?

I understand that `PaperTrail.enabled = false` is possible, but I don't want other changes being made a the same time to not be recorded.

My ideal solution would be something along the lines of:

`PaperTrail.disable { version.reify.save }`

Answer (score 4):

I once accomplished something similar by mixing in something like this:

```
def without_papertrail
  PaperTrail.disable
  yield if block_given?
  PaperTrail.enable
end
```

Then you can do something similar to your objective

```
without_papertrail { version.reify.save }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am using, but it still turns PaperTrail off completely instead of just turning it off for the objects being reified.

Answer (score 3):

You can disable paper trail for a particular model, using either of two syntaxes:

```
m = MyModel.find(123)
m.paper_trail.without_versioning do
  # No versioning of `m` happens in this block
end
```

Note: Since it is called on a model instance, it seems as though this might naturally disable versioning on just that instance, but this syntax disables versioning on the entire model.

The other syntax:

```
MyModel.paper_trail.disable
# No versioning of MyModel happens here
MyModel.paper_trail.enable
```

Comment: The API was recently depcreated. The new API is: `PaperTrail.request.disable_model(MyModel)`

Answer (score 2):

As of today, gem version *10.3.0*, the correct way to achieve this is, as per the [gem documentation](https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail#per-class):

```
PaperTrail.request.disable_model(Banana)
# changes to Banana model do not create versions,
# but eg. changes to Kiwi model do.
PaperTrail.request.enable_model(Banana)
```

Answer (score 0):

from the readme: https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail#7-testing

```
PaperTrail.enabled = false
```